# Mostrar dato de un selecct con JQuery, si el valor viene de MySql

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

Como mostrar la opción seleccionada de un select con JQuery, en un formulario al momento de modificar el dato, si el valor del objeto seleccionado viene de MySql

Este es mi código php...

```
  <div class="form-group" id="selectRama">
      <label for="rama">Rama</label>
                    <?php
                    //Consultar la base de datos
                    $consultar_mysql_rama = "SELECT * FROM RAMA";
                    $resultadoRama = mysqli_query($conexion, $consultar_mysql_rama);
                    ?>
        <select id="rama" name="rama" class="form-control" required>
          <option value="">Seleccione la rama</option>
                        <?php while ($lista=mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultadoRama)) { ?>
                            <option value="<?php echo $lista['RAMA_ID']?>"><?php echo $lista=utf8_encode($lista['NOMBRE'])?></option>
                        <?php } ?>
        </select>
    </div>
```

Y con JQuery esto es lo que estoy haciendo...

```
$('#rama').html(rama);
```

Pero no se mes nuestra el valor seleccionado el en formulario a la hora de modificar...

Comment: agrega un ejemplo de tu respuesta del php, y el código de lo que has intentado.

Comment: `$('#rama').html(rama)`;   de donde viene tu variable `rama`?

Answer (score 0):

Supongo que tu codigo genera una estructura html parecida a esta:

```
<select id='valores'>
  <option id='opt1'>1</option>
  <option id='opt2'>2</option>
  <option id='opt3'>3</option>
</select>
```

Si es asi, el codigo JS que necesitas es:

```
$('#valores').change(function(){
    alert($('#valores').val());
});
```

Obvio solo te dara el valor cuando cambies la seleccion, pero basicamente lo unico que debes hacer para obetener el valor del select es:

```
$('#valores).val();
```

Si quieres el texto que tiene el select seria:

```
$('#valores').find(':selected').text();
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ttwvetvk/2/

Si tienes alguna comenta, Suerte.

**Actualizacion**

Muy bien, ahora que veo el bloque html que genera tu codigo mi recomendacion seria que cuando se termine de cargar tu pagina, le asignes el attributo id o tus tags `<option></option>`

Lo puedes hacer con el siguiente codigo:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#idSelect').find('option').each(function(i){
        $(this).attr('id','opt'+i);
    });
});
```

Esto asgignara un id incremental a tus opciones y podras manipularlas con un simple ciclo for en js.

Si te surge otra duda, comenta.
Suerte

Comment: Los datos del select son dinámicos ya que los cargos de MySql..

Comment: Y estoy recuperando el valor así: $('#rama').html(rama);

Comment: Pero no me muestra el valor seleccionado.

Comment: Me podrias mostrar el bloque html que te genera tu codigo?

Comment: Actualice mi respuesta, no habia notado la fraccion de codigo que agregaste a tu pregunta.

Answer (score 0):

Concuerdo con el amigo de arriba de todos modos te dejo un ejemplo mas corriedno

```js
$('#valores').change(function(){
    alert('La opción seleccionada es :  '+$('#valores').val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id='valores'>
  <option id='opt1'>Ivan</option>
  <option id='opt2'>Joel</option>
  <option id='opt3'>Jose</option>
</select>
```